# postgresql ipv6 inet subtraction

Tags: postgresql, ipv6, inet

I want to convert ipv6 inet address to 128 bit.

How can I do in postgresql?

I get the below error when I try to convert inet to numeric

```
select ('fe80::a128:d239:d6c0:3598'::inet '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0'::inet)::numeric;

ERROR:  result is out of range
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem, did you find any solution?